# How can you tell the difference between "il parle" and "ils parlent"?

Tags: prononciation, verbes

As far as I can tell "il parle" and "ils parlent" are pronounced identically. So how can you tell the difference between them? The same goes for "elle/elles"+verb and all other verbs where the third person singular is pronounced the same as the third person plural.

Please answer in English only! I am learning French but I can't understand it yet.

Comment: The "ent" ending for verb is always silent, it's a conjugation ending only to show the plural.

Comment: @Quidam Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's too short to be an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: @Quidam It sounds like you were trying to answer the question since you're not trying to improve the question.

Comment: Very annoying as with Duolingo hearts are lost when the reply is wrong. I find ils. V il and elles v Elle very difficult in some situations.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Phonetically speaking, you can't tell the difference between them; they are pronounced the same. And yes, it goes for all the other verbs where the third person singular is pronounced the same as the third person plural, *except* in cases where the verb starts with a vowel. In those cases, there is often a liaison made when it's plural. For example, *ils écoutent* will be pronounced "*il (z)écoute*" as opposed to "*il écoute*" for singular.

So how do we *ever* tell the difference between the two? Context. It is usually fairly clear from context if it's singular or plural. There are also often other words in a sentence that will clear up the meaning if the subject is muddy (e.g. are we talking about the group or just one individual). Such words can be *tous, ensemble, seul*, etc.

Comment: I'm using Duolingo to learn French at the moment and in some of the questions it asks you to translate a spoken phrase with no context. So I guess even a native speaker will struggle with those ambiguous questions! I feel a lot better about being marked "wrong" now!

Comment: @CJDennis Exactly in the same situation and that made me arrive here.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, we rely on the context to determine whether the pronoun is the singular "il"/"elle" or the plural "ils"/"elles".

For example :

> Ils sont partis. *(They are gone.)*

The auxiliary "sont" is plural, so the pronoun before it is plural as well.

While in :

> Il est parti. *(He is gone.)*

The auxiliary "est" is singular, so the pronoun before it is singular as well.

For verbs like "parler" (to speak) that don't change phonetically between singular and plural ("il parle" and "ils parlent"), the number must be implicit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the biggest problem comes in cases where the verb ends with a vowel. Eg. Il parle vs Ils parlent (He speaks vs They speak). In this case the verbs "parle and parlent" sound exactly the same.

However in cases where the verb ends with a consonant there seems to be an audible difference. Eg. Il part vs Ils partent (He leaves vs They leave). In this case the verbs "part and partent" sound slightly different where in singular the "t" at the end is a lot more silent than in the one in the plural.

In cases where the verb starts with a vowel or where the auxiliary word like "sont" is in use, it becomes a lot easier.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE. A little confused, this seems to repeat parts of the other answers. *Il parle* does end in a vowel (seen with inversion parle-t-il). How does the difference between parler and partir answer the question? I encourage you to take the [tour] and see the [help].

Comment: Not all cases when the verb ends with a consonant are distinguishable ... for example, *il croit* and *ils croient* are pronounced identically.

Answer (score -2):

Just seeing this question 3 years later, but I have noticed that in DuoLingo, and there isn’t always context from which you can determine singular or plural form.  But, I’ve also noticed in pronunciation that there is a slightly prolonged, more pronounced release of the final syllable in the plural form. So instead of “elles” sounding short like “elle”, it will sound more more like “el-uh”. “Écrivent” instead of sounding like “ècrive” will sound more like “écriv-ffe”. It is ever so slight. You can hear it better when you listen to the slow version. Truth is, the average person speaking casually in French will probably not make such distinction, so unfortunately, you’ll have to rely on context in most situations, as verbs like “être”—which make the form obvious—are not always used.

Comment: The course editors have confirmed many times (particularly Sitesurf) that the audio is identical. They now allow both singular and plural in these cases.